# rewrite rules on nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

as previously i use apache for webservers, but now i want to migrate server to vps and i use nginx server. I have htaccess file here :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/(.*).pdf$ /generator/pdfviewer.php?kiwod=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and i try to rewrite with this script:

## nginx configuration

```
location / { rewrite ^/(.*).pdf$ /generator/pdfviewer.php?kiwod=$1 break; }
```

but that script did not work . Please advise me for the correct script and where i put the code on nginx configuration?

please help me guys

Comment: Server Fault would be a more appropriate place since this is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put rewrite outside of location, in server:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.org  example.org;
    rewrite  (.*)  http://www.example.org$1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks Pierangelo Orizio , but i am beginner. please advise me step by step to put thats code on my server.

Comment: There is something wrong in your answer there are brackets missing